# Regular expression for laravel username and #tags

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-8

how can I set up a Regular expression for @username and #example on post field form, just like Twitter , when a user uses #hashtag in there post I will like to automatically save it to tag table and when a user uses @john symbol I would like to automatically notify the user he /she has been mentioned , please what is the logic behind this I don't have idea on how to start

im getting this error

BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Livewire\createPost::tag does not exist.

```
 public function createPost()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $this->validate();

           $posts = Post::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'school_id' => $this->school,
                'body' => $this->body,
                'is_anon' => $this->is_anon,
                $url = \url(route('posts.show', $this->id)),

            ]);

            preg_match_all('/(?<=#)(\w+)/mi', $this->body, $matchedTags, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
            foreach($matchedTags as $matchedTag) {
                if(!$tag = tag::where('name', $matchedTag[0])->first()) {
                    $tag = tag::create(['name' => $matchedTag[0]]);
                }
                $this->tags()->attach($tag->id);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your input string is `$str`, you can use these:

```php
preg_match_all('/(?<=@)(\w+)/mi', $str, $atSignMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
preg_match_all('/(?<=#)(\w+)/mi', $str, $poundMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

and then you can print the `$atSignMatches` and `$poundMatches` which are the resulting values.

More info on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Update: Steps

These are the steps to extract users and make notifications.

1. Get Request payload.
2. Extract Tags (using #)
3. Create Tag records in table
4. Extract mentions (using @)
5. Create notification for mentioners

```php
public function save(Request $request) {
{
    $post = Post::create($request->all());
    
    $content = $post->content;

    preg_match_all('/(?<=#)(\w+)/mi', $content, $matchedTags, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    foreach($matchedTags as $matchedTag) {
        if(!$tag = Tag::where('name', $matchedTag[0])->first()) {
            $tag = Tag::create(['name' => $matchedTag[0]]);
        }
        $post->tags()->attach($tag->id);
    }

    preg_match_all('/(?<=@)(\w+)/mi', $content, $matchedMentions, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    foreach($matchedMentions as $matchedMention) {
        if($user = User::where('username', $matchedMention[0])->first()) {
            $user->notifications()->create([
                'post_id' => $post->id,
                'type' => "MENTION",
                'seen' => false,
                'time' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Make sure to change the `tag` and `notification` creation implementation matching your table structure.

Comment: thanks for the reply but please , can you provide me step on how to do this please

Comment: @kiki I updated the answer but it will need to be changed based on your structure and database schema.

Comment: @kiki Vote up and accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: please im gettng syntax error kind check the code above

Comment: @kiki You have to run the `preg_match_all` and `foreach` outside of `create` method!